# Scrapyrt not using callback functions

Tags: django, web-scraping, django-views, scrapy, scrapy-splash

these are my files:

views.py

```
from uuid import uuid4
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse
from time import sleep
import os
import json

import requests
    

def is_valid_url(url):
    validate = URLValidator()
    try:
        validate(url) # check if url format is valid
    except ValidationError:
        return False

return True

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST',])
def getProduct(request):

    url = request.POST['url']

    if not url:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Missing  args'})
    
    if not is_valid_url(url):
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'URL is invalid'})

    data = {
        "request": {
            "url": str(url),
            "callback": "start_requests",
            "dont_filter": "false"
        },
        "spider_name": "GetinfoSpider"
    }

    scrapyrt = 'http://127.0.0.1:9081/crawl.json'

    try:
        #print(str(requests.post(scrapyrt, data = data)))
        r = requests.post(scrapyrt, json = data)
        print(r)
        return JsonResponse({'data': r})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})
```

this is my spider file getInfo.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

from ..items import WallmartItem

import logging


class GetinfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name:str = 'GetinfoSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.walmart.com']

    script1:str = '''
        function main(splash, args)
            splash.private_mode_enabled = false
            url = args.url
            assert(splash:go(url))
            assert(splash:wait(1))
            splash:set_viewport_full()
            return splash:html()
        end
    '''


    def start_requests(self, url):

        yield scrapy.Request(str(url), callback=self.parse_item, meta={
            'splash': {
                'args': {
                    # set rendering arguments here
                    'lua_source': self.script1

                },

                # optional parameters
                'endpoint': 'render.html',  # optional; default is render.json
            }
        })

    def parse_item(self, response):
        logging.log(logging.WARNING, "This is a warning")
        item = WallmartItem()
        #specs = response.css
    
    
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-overview"]/div/div[3]/div/h1//text()').get(),
        item['price'] = response.css('span.price-characteristic::attr(content)').getall(),
        item['deliveryDate'] = response.css('p.no-margin::text').get(),
        item['pictures'] = response.css('img.prod-alt-image-carousel-image--left::attr(src)').getall(),
        item['description'] = response.css('div.about-desc ::text').getall(),


        yield item
```

everything seems to be working fine until i send the post request with the data dict in views, i got this response:

```
2020-10-21 12:09:28 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.site/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-10-21 12:09:29 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.site/ip/Fruit-of-the-Loom-Men-s-and-Big-Men-s-Eversoft-Fleece-Full-Zip-Hoodie-Jacket-up-to-Size-3XL/630234494> (referer: None)
2020-10-21 12:09:29 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-10-21 12:09:29 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1142,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 113270,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.577416,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 18, 9, 29, 136179),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 13,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'offsite/filtered': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 18, 9, 27, 558763)}
2020-10-21 12:09:29 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

No Item or information to parse, i think the problem could be that scrapyrt is not calling my callbacks functions, but I'm still not quite sure

any information will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem was the way that the request was being handled, if anyone have this same problem just make sure that the URL is the one youre passing to the callback

something like this:

```
def start_requests(self, request):
    url = request.url
    return SplashRequest(
            url=str(url),
            callback=self.parse_item, 
            endpoint='execute',
            args = {
                'lua_source': self.script1
        }
    )
```